# In datagridview , How to get values from sql server and display in comboxcolumn?

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I have a Grid in my windows application project .. In Grid , i have DROPDOWN in one column , in that column how to display data fetched from SQLSERVER . THANKS IN ADVANCE .. Below is my coding ...

```
  connstring();
      conn.Open();
       adap = new SqlDataAdapter("gvretrieve_ip", conn);


ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
 adap.Fill(ds, "dt");

 foreach (DataColumn DC in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
{

  }

  dataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];


    int index = 5; 

         DataGridViewComboBoxColumn newCol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
      dataGridView2.Columns.Insert(index, newCol);
    dataGridView2.Columns[index].HeaderText = dataGridView2.Columns[index + 1].HeaderText;
     newCol.MaxDropDownItems = 4;



            dataGridView2.Columns.RemoveAt(index + 1);
```